# Confusions about Google drive rate limits

Tags: rest, google-api, google-drive-api, rate-limiting

I want to use Google Drive API for my new web app

I found below things from Google documentation.

```
Batch multiple calls into a single request using the Google Drive API, especially when changing file metadata for many items that belong to the same user. See Google Drive API.
Do not allow a service account to create more than 400,000 files on behalf of a given user account.

The default quota limits for Drive API are 20,000 calls every 100 seconds, both per user and per project. This limit applies to the sum of read and write calls.

The rate of Drive API write requests is limited—avoid exceeding 3 requests per second of sustained write or insert requests, per account. Note: This rate limit can’t be increased.
```

I have a Google account `myapp@gmail.com` with which I have registered my app let's say `Vishal Cloud App`

1. User A (`a@gmail.com`) registered on my app and granted Google drive access using OAuth2 way
2. User B (`b@gmail.com`) registered on my app and granted Google drive access using OAuth2 way

My app is uploading some files on behalf of users A and B.

I can't figure out how many files I can upload per second per registered user account on my app without any issues. Can someone help to understand this?

Answer (score -3):

To my knowledge, Aim to upload files at a rate of fewer than 2.5 write requests per second per user account, utilize batch requests for multiple changes, and keep in mind the 400,000 file limit for service accounts. Monitor API usage and stay within the default quota limits of 20,000 calls every 100 seconds, both per user and per project.

Comment: Hi @Code_Sphinx_TSK  `400,000 file limit for service accounts` per sec, per min, per day ?? Do you have reference documentation this? Does that mean my app can't upload more than 400000 files all registered users?

Comment: There is no specific documented limit of 400,000 files for service accounts. Monitor API usage and stay within the documented quotas. Refer to the official Google Drive API documentation for accurate information.

Comment: If you're happy with that please give me an upvote that will be a lot of help!

Comment: sorry but it does not answer what I have asked, otherwise I even accept answer and upvote everytime

Comment: @Code_Sphinx_TSK you are contradicting your answer. Of course the 400k stuff is documented `Do not allow a service account to create more than 400,000 files on behalf of a given user account`. https://support.google.com/a/answer/10445916?hl=en#:~:text=The%20default%20quota%20limits%20for,or%20insert%20requests%2C%20per%20account.